# How do I set an Icon for a Qpushbutton in a GUI with placeholders in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, icons, pyqt, qt-designer

**Solution:**
My fault: The file where adding the icon to the button is used via the "placeholder" function from QtDesigner. The Main-programm located in a different folder searches in its own folder for the icon, not in the folder from the "imported" file. So you just have to add the path to the icon:

```
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
icon1_path = os.path.join(dirpath,"arrow_down.ico")
icon = QtGui.QPixmap(icon1_path)
```

---

I want to create a Qpushbutton with an Icon instead of text:

```
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("arrow_down.png"))
self.ui.pb_down.setIcon(icon)
```

But this doesn't work. Neither this works:

```
self.ui.pb_down.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("arrow_down.png"))
```

Theres is no Error-message, the icon just doesn't appear.

If I add the Icon via Qt Designer, the icon is shown in the Qt Desiger itself, but when running the programm, the icon disappears again. Does anybody know what's going on?

Im using python 2.7 and Windows 7

**Edit:**
Using @Chris Aung code, I get a button with icon.

```
    button = QtGui.QPushButton()
    self.setCentralWidget(button)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("arrow_down.ico"))
    print button.icon().isNull()  #Returns true if the icon is empty; otherwise returns false.
    #output = False
```

But if I use exactly this code in my GUI, it just doesnt add the icon.

```
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("arrow_down.ico"))
    self.ui.pb_down.setIcon(icon)
    print self.ui.pb_down.icon().isNull()
    # output = True
```

I have no idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create the `QPushButton` with Icon without any problem using the code you have provided.The following is the code I used.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("TEST")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("add.png"))
        button.setIcon(icon)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I suggest you to check your `png` image again(or try with some other `png` image). I am not totally confident that it will fix the problem but I had the similar problem before and using a different `.png` image seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and is auto generated by pyqt when you convert a .ui file to .py with the [pyuic4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#the-uic-module) tool.

```
    Icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    Icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("SOME FILE")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    button.setIcon(Icon)
    button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))
```

If you use this, you will also have to define "_fromUtf8" at the top of your module as:

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
```

Comment: already tried it using the Qtdesigner. The Qtdesigner itself shows the icon, but when running the programm theres no icon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have text rendered on that button?
Try playing with the icon size setIconSize(), to begin with you can try setting it to the rect of the pixmap.

Comment: already tried it, changing sizes of the icon and/or pushbutton doesnt help.